# .then does not exist in type void in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I know that there is a solution available to the following query but I am a noob in angular2 and do not what should be added in the void function please Help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOrcx.png)

```
export class PasswordResetPage {

  email : string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams , 
              public userservice :UserProvider,
              public AlertCtrl :AlertController) { }

  reset(){
    let alert = this.AlertCtrl.create({
      buttons :['ok']
    });
    this.userservice.passwordreset(this.email).then((res: any)=>{
      if(res.success){
        alert.setTitle('Email sent');
        alert.setSubTitle('please follow the instructions in the email
                           to reset the password')
      }
      else{
        alert.setTitle('failed');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: you need not add anything just bind it to a variable.

Comment: `passwordReset` obviously doesn't return anything or has a return type `void` declared (even when it returns something).
Please add the code as text to the question instead of just a link to a screenshot.

Comment: thank you for the reply here is the code,

Answer (score 1):

It's important to know what the return type of this service call is:

```
this.userservice.passwordreset(this.email)
```

.then is only applicable if the service call returns a Promise, and it's more likely that it's returning an Observable, so you'd need to subscribe to that to get the value.

```
this.userservice.passwordreset(this.email)
.subscribe(
      res => {
         alert.setTitle('Email sent');
         alert.setSubTitle('please follow the instructions in the email to reset the password')
      },
      err => {
          console.log('Error', err),
          alert.setTitle('failed')
      }
);
```